# Outlook VBA AppointmentItem.Move creating a copy

Tags: vba, outlook

When using the `Move` method on an `AppointmentItem` in an Outlook macro, I lose the ability to receive updates because it is creating a copy of the item instead of truly moving it.  This behavior causes the item to no longer be linked with the original and will not retain item updates as a result.

I want to replicate through VBA the cut/paste behavior you get which is able to maintain the original object and does not cause updates to be lost.

I believe this has something to do with the GlobalAppointmentID based on searching around, however I have not been able to find a way to actually move the appointment.

The code I'm using is below.  GetFolderFromPath is a helper function to just return a folder object from the path, which works perfectly well.

```
Sub MoveItem()
    Dim targetPath As String: targetPath = "\\tnolan@microsoft.com\Calendar\OOFS"

    If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox ("No item selected")
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Dim targetFolder As Outlook.Folder
        Set targetFolder = GetFolderFromPath(targetPath)

        For x = 1 To Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count
            Dim oSelected As Variant
            Set oSelected = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(x)

            If oSelected.Class = olAppointment Then
                Dim NS As NameSpace: Set NS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
                Dim oAppt As AppointmentItem: Set oAppt = NS.GetItemFromID(oSelected.EntryID)
                oAppt.Move targetFolder
                Set oAppt = Nothing
                Set NS = Nothing
            End If
            Set oSelected = Nothing
        Next x
        Set targetFolder = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Outlook processes incoming meeting updates/deletions only against the default Calendar folder. If you move an appointment to a different folder, meeting update in your Inbox will create a new appointment in the default Calendar folder.

Comment: That's not true.  Because if I (in the UI) right-click on a calendar appointment, choose cut, and then paste it into a different calendar folder (or just simply click and drag it to a different folder), it will maintain the appointment with any updates that are made.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with my code for a little bit, I've found that this code works for me in a similar situation:

```
oAppt.CopyTo(targetFolder, olCopyAsAccept)
oAppt.Delete
```

I have a feeling that for some reason the `AppointmentItem.Move` command passes as `olCreateAppointment` which would always create a new `GlobalAppointmentID`.

However, this still has a side-effect of responding accept to the Appointment.